# How to properly add css file to php and html?

Tags: php, html, css

I have one problem. I have three files
header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/style.css">
    <title>System stypendialny</title>
</head>
<body>
```

index.php

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="logo">
        <h1>Nazwa strony</h1>
        <p>slogan</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="title_head">Lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            <h2>Witaj na naszej stronie</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis eget tortor vitae purus bibendum ornare at sit amet mauris. Aenean adipiscing velit a        tellus sodales quis commodo metus congue. Cras ac erat eget urna faucibus pellentesque sit amet eget metus. Vestibulum ac hendrerit sapien. Vivamus        consectetur dui at nisi dictum tincidunt ac ut purus. Praesent id ornare velit. Morbi fringilla, justo nec tincidunt hendrerit, mi ante ornare magna,        id sodales dolor erat quis ante. Sed vel adipiscing nisl. Etiam lectus turpis, fermentum quis vehicula at, elementum vitae nibh. Duis at leo eu purus        aliquet rutrum. Phasellus posuere, ante condimentum sagittis venenatis, sem tellus venenatis arcu, ac iaculis quam lorem at urna.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar">
            <h2>O nas</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis eget tortor vitae purus bibendum ornare at sit amet mauris. Aenean adipiscing velit a        tellus sodales quis commodo metus congue. Cras ac erat eget urna faucibus pellentesque sit amet eget metus.
            </p>
            <h2>Polecam</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>&copy Wszelkie prawa zastrzeżone. <br /> Projekt: <a href="http://www.templatki.net">Darmowe Szablony Stron</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and view.php where I include header.php to another files

```
<?php


class View
{

    function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function Render()
    {
        require_once 'views/Header.php';
        $file = 'views/' . $this->controller . '/' . $this->page . '.php';
        if (file_exists($file))
            require_once $file;
        else {
            $this->message = "Nie znaleziono pliku";
            require_once 'views/Error.php';
        }
        require_once 'views/Footer.php';
    }

}
```

The problem is that the file css doesn't include and I don't know why. Do you have any suggestions? A tried everything but didn't work.

Comment: I assume you're talking about the `resources/style.css` file in `header.php`? If so, it's likely because the path is not correct. Where does your `include` file live?

Comment: Why are you choosing to do it this way? It the header conditional? What does the compiled html look like?

Comment: Yes. I'm talking about this. This is files tree
1. resources
    - style.css
2. views
    - header.php
    - view.php 
    - index.php

Comment: @sheriffderek because I use MVC

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely path related but you can be certain by inspecting the page with developer tools (`control + shift + i` in most browsers).

Depending on where your `view.php` file is living, you'll need to adjust the `link` to the `CSS` file. Right now you just have `/resources/style.css` but everything else is included using the preface `views/filename`. If you supply your directory structure we might be able to give a solid solution but this should get you going in the correct direction as well.

UPDATE:

It seems you need to move up one directory using `../` since the style sheet does live in the `view` directory. Try changing the link to:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/style.css">
```

Comment: This is a part of structure

 - libs
    - view.php
 - resources
    - style.css 
 - views
    - index
     - index.php
    - header.php

Comment: Did you inspect with developer tools? Looking at the `resources` tab in that will tell you what resources have failed to load.

Comment: How can I do this in phpStorm?

Comment: You should do this in a browser, not an editor. Is this a live site that I can review?